# limiting tabbing to a custom in-window message box

Tags: c#, wpf

I have made a custom MessageBox for my application and it launches as a `UserControl`. I have two buttons inside it and I would like to allow users to press Tab to switch between `Buttons`. However, since it's a `UserControl` overlaying the content, Pressing tab more than twice makes the focus go in the background on elements that aren't supposed to be tabbed at.

I can't figure out a good idea how to prevent this, I've thought of making a method that will select all elements and make their `IsTabStop` values to false and then restore them later, but I think that would be more of a problem then a solution.

Is there a way around this to limit tabbing only to the `UserControl`?

I would also appreciate advice on working with the message box.. the whole messagebox is an async function that has an infinitive loop until the answer is given. Is there another way to stop the application until one of the message box options was selected?

Comment: Duplicate of [Restrict tab order to a single user control (WPF)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005723/restrict-tab-order-to-a-single-user-control-wpf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crowcoder's reference has lead to correct MSDN page where I found my solution:

```
dialog = new UCMessageBox("Are you sure you want to exit the application?", MBType.YesNo);
AppMessageBox.Children.Add(dialog);
KeyboardNavigation.SetTabNavigation(dialog, KeyboardNavigationMode.Cycle);
```

The key was to call `.SetTabNavigation` function and direct it to my dialog (custom `UserControl` for the message box) and setting the `KeyboardNavigationMode` to `Cycle`.

After closing the UC rest of the application continued normally regarding navigation.